# Send email through Spring mvc Application

Tags: spring, email, spring-mvc, frameworks, sendmail

Can anyone help me in sending email from **spring framework**? Recently i googled but not getting perfect solution. i want perfect solution. I am getting errors when following some examples.  I am using **spring framework version 4.3.6.RELEASE**.

Comment: there is no perfect solution. kindly mention the errors you are getting.

Comment: Please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960316/unable-to-send-email-trying-to-connect-to-host-smtp-mail-gmail-com-port-587

Answer (score 0):

> Add below Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Here is sample code for sending email

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;

public class TestClass {


    public String sendEmail() throws Exception {

        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        mailSender.setHost("your host");
        mailSender.setPort(587);
        mailSender.setUsername("Your email");
        mailSender.setPassword("password");

        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo("To");
                message.setFrom(mailSender.getUsername());
                message.setSubject("Subject");
                message.setBcc(mailSender.getUsername());
                message.setText("Body", true);
            }
        };
        mailSender.send(preparator);

        return "Mail Sent Successfully.";
    }

}
```

you need to set some param like below

- Host Name
- Port Number
- Email Address
- Password
- To
- Subject
- Body

It might help you for sending email via spring application